# Codeigniter DB select logic error

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

In my DB I have a bunch of products. In my products table I have a column called `active` which defaults to `1` (which means it's 'active') When I delete a product instead of deleting the row I just change the active column to `0`

I also have a search function that searches products by name or description etc. I'm using codeigniter to as a framework. This is the code I have that generates the query:

```
$search_query = $this->db->from('company_products')
->where('company_products.active', 1)
->or_like(array('name'=> $keywords, 'model'=> $keywords, 'brand'=> $keywords, 'description'=> $keywords))
->order_by('id', 'RANDOM')
->get();
```

This code generates this mysql query:

```
SELECT `company_products`.*
FROM (`company_products`)
WHERE `company_products`.`active` =  1
AND  `name`  LIKE '%chair%'
OR  `model`  LIKE '%chair%'
OR  `brand`  LIKE '%chair%'
OR  `description`  LIKE '%chair%'
```

After 'deleting' a product (changing the active column to 0) the product still shows up on search results. This is what I suspect is going on on the code:

```
(SELECT a product WHERE active = 1 - AND - name LIKE %search_string%) 
 - OR - 
(SELECT a product WHERE model LIKE %search_string%)
 - OR - 
(SELECT a product WHERE brand LIKE %search_string%)
 - OR - 
(SELECT a product WHERE description LIKE %search_string%)
```

But this is what I want:

```
(SELECT a product WHERE active = 1) 

 - AND - 

{ (SELECT a product WHERE model LIKE %search_string%) 
- OR - 
(SELECT a product WHERE model LIKE %search_string%) 
- OR - 
(SELECT a product WHERE brand LIKE %search_string%) 
- OR - 
(SELECT a product WHERE description LIKE %search_string%) }
```

I hope my pseudo-code isn't too confusing. I'd like to accomplish this using codeigniter's active record class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Active record isn't going to do this on it's own, you need to group those or's otherwise they are working as an or against the whole where part of the query. You need to build the WHERE statement in complex queries manually, personally in these cases I just don't bother with active record at all but if you really want to use it you can do it like this:

```
$where = "`company_products`.`active` =  1 AND (`name`  LIKE '%$keywords%' 
OR `model`  LIKE '%$keywords%' OR `brand`  LIKE '%$keywords%' OR 
`description`  LIKE '%$keywords%')";
$search_query = $this->db->from('company_products')
->where($where)
->order_by('id', 'RANDOM')
->get();
```

Comment: what would you do for security? escape $keyword? htmlspecialchars?
I liked the active record because of the preexisting security against SQL injections and such.

Comment: I could be wrong but I believe because active record is still building the query it is still escaped like it would be if you used the way you were doing it.

Answer (score 0):

use brackets:

```
SELECT `company_products`.*
FROM (`company_products`)
WHERE `company_products`.`active` =  1
AND  (`name`  LIKE '%chair%'
 OR  `model`  LIKE '%chair%'
 OR  `brand`  LIKE '%chair%'
 OR  `description`  LIKE '%chair%')
```

Read about [Operator Precedence](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/operator-precedence.html) in MySQL (basically it applies to all RDBMS)

Comment: He stated he wanted to continue using CI's active record to do his query.

Comment: I think CI should allow somehow to group the conditions. Many other query builders allow this